# EF Core final select projection not generating correct SQL when using UNION

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, projection, iqueryable

I have 5 tables:

- Student
- StudentLocation
- Location
- Region
- RegionDetail

In the below code when my `IQueryable` is without the UNION, the select projection is helping in generating the SQL with the needed columns and ignoring all other un-necessary columns. But when I  include the UNION it looks like the select projection is not helping. The generated SQL contains all the columns from all the entities in the query.

Just like the first query

```cs
locationStudentsQuery
    .Select(x => new StudentForDynamicQuery { StudentId = x.StudentId })
    .ToList()
```

How can I make the second query with UNION

```cs
locationStudentsQuery.Union(regionStudentsQuery)
    .Select(x => new StudentForDynamicQuery { StudentId = x.StudentId })
    .ToList()
```

to generate SQL with needed columns only?

```cs
public class StudentForDynamicQuery { public long StudentId { get; set; } }

var locationStudentsQuery = context.Set<StudentEntity>().AsNoTracking()
    .Join(context.Set<StudentLocationEntity>().AsNoTracking(),
        outer => outer.StudentId,
        inner => inner.StudentId,
        (outer, inner) => new { outer.StudentId, inner.LocationId })
    .Join(context.Set<LocationEntity>().AsNoTracking(),
        outer => outer.LocationId,
        inner => inner.LocationId,
        (outer2, inner2) => new { outer2.StudentId });

var result = locationStudentsQuery.Select(x => new StudentForDynamicQuery { StudentId = x.StudentId }).ToList();
```

```sql
SELECT r.student_id
FROM student AS r
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT r0.location_id, r0.student_id
        FROM student_location AS r0) AS t ON r.student_id = t.student_id
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT l.location_id
        FROM location AS l) AS t0 ON t.location_id = t0.location_id;
```

```sql
var locationStudentsQuery = context.Set<StudentEntity>().AsNoTracking()
    .Join(context.Set<StudentLocationEntity>().AsNoTracking(),
        outer => outer.StudentId,
        inner => inner.StudentId,
        (outer, inner) => new { outer.StudentId, inner.LocationId })
    .Join(context.Set<LocationEntity>().AsNoTracking(),
        outer => outer.LocationId,
        inner => inner.LocationId,
        (outer2, inner2) => new { outer2.StudentId });

    var regionStudentsQuery = query
    .Join(context.Set<StudentLocationEntity>().AsNoTracking(),
        outer => outer.StudentId,
        inner => inner.StudentId,
        (outer, inner) => new { outer.StudentId, inner.RegionId })
    .Join(context.Set<RegionDetailEntity>().AsNoTracking(),
        outer => outer.RegionId,
        inner => inner.RegionId,
        (outer2, inner2) => new { outer2.StudentId, inner2.LocationId })
    .Join(context.Set<LocationEntity>().AsNoTracking(),
        outer => outer.LocationId,
        inner => inner.LocationId,
        (outer3, inner3) => new { outer3.StudentId });
var result = locationStudentsQuery.Union(regionStudentsQuery).Select(x => new StudentForDynamicQuery { StudentId = x.StudentId }).ToList();
```

```sql
SELECT r.student_id AS "StudentId"
FROM student AS r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 

    r0.student_location_id, r0.create_by, r0.create_date_time,
    r0.last_change_by, r0.last_change_date_time, r0.location_id,
    r0.student_id, r0.region_id

    FROM student_location AS r0
) AS t ON r.student_id = t.student_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 

    l.location_id, l.city, l.country_code, l.create_by,
    l.create_date_time, l.last_change_by, l.last_change_date_time,
    l.postal_code, l.state_code

    FROM location AS l
) AS t0 ON t.location_id = t0.location_id
UNION
SELECT r1.student_id AS "StudentId"
FROM student AS r1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 

    r2.student_location_id, r2.create_by, r2.create_date_time,
    r2.last_change_by, r2.last_change_date_time, r2.location_id,
    r2.student_id, r2.region_id

    FROM student_location AS r2
) AS t1 ON r1.student_id = t1.student_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 

    r3.region_detail_id, r3.create_by, r3.create_date_time,
    r3.last_change_by, r3.last_change_date_time, r3.location_id,
    r3.region_id

    FROM region_detail AS r3
) AS t2 ON t1.region_id = t2.region_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 

    l0.location_id, l0.city, l0.country_code, l0.create_by,
    l0.create_date_time, l0.last_change_by, l0.last_change_date_time,
    l0.postal_code, l0.state_code

    FROM location AS l0
) AS t3 ON t2.location_id = t3.location_id
```

Comment: `Union` means  that SQL Server hast to make distinct query on the set of fields.  EF should  not optimise projection, otherwise you  will have different records count.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv any thoughts on how to optimize my LINQ statement for efficient querying ? I just want to avoid selecting all columns when I know for sure they are not needed

Comment: Have you tried to project both queries before `union`? like `locationStudentsQuery.Select(x => new StudentForDynamicQuery { StudentId = x.StudentId }).Union(regionStudentsQuery.Select(x => new StudentForDynamicQuery { StudentId = x.StudentId })).ToList();`

Comment: @sarvpk, reformatted your code to understand problem clearly. Unfortunately you can do nothing here. SQL is correct but not optimally generated. It is issue with EF itself.